# Trouble calculating average change of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I have to write a code that allows the user to calculate the average mileage change from week to week that they run but am having some issues and was hoping to get a little guidance. The program basically allows the user to enter how many weeks of data they have as well as all the corresponding values for miles ran and stores the values in an array. I think I am really close but for whatever reason when I try to calculate the sum of differences for all the values in the array, it is only storing the difference between the first two values in the array and not the rest therefore giving me an incorrect result. This part of the code in particular is where i'm having issues:

```
sumOfDifferences += (y[i+1] - y[i]); 
average = (sumOfDifferences) / (weeksData - 1);
```

Here is what I have so far. I appreciate any help I can get

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunAnalyzer
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\n How many weeks of data do you have? ");

            int weeksData = input.nextInt();        

        double [] y = new double [weeksData];       double average = 0;     double sumOfDifferences = 0;    
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) 
        {

            System.out.print("\nEnter miles run for week " + (i + 1) + ": ");

                y[i] = input.nextDouble();


        }

            for  (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
            {
                sumOfDifferences += (y[i+1] - y[i]); 
                average = (sumOfDifferences) / (weeksData - 1);

                if (y[i+1] <= y[i])
                {
                    System.out.print("\n You're weekly mileage is NOT increasing!");

                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Your weekly mileage is increasing!");

                    break;
                } 


            }

            System.out.print("\nAverage weekly mileage change: " + average);

    }

}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: You `break` out of the loop in any case during first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the first iteration you `break` out of the loop. (You have a break in your `if` and `else` so no matter which path it takes it will break):

```
for  (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
{
        sumOfDifferences += (y[i+1] - y[i]); 
        average = (sumOfDifferences) / (weeksData - 1);
        if (y[i+1] <= y[i]) {
            System.out.print("\n You're weekly mileage is NOT increasing!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your weekly mileage is increasing!");
            break;
        }
}
```

You will want to remove these. However once you do you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error as on the last iteration you will call `y[i + 1]` when `i` is equal to `y.length -1`. This will not be a valid index. You only want to iterate until `<y.length-1`:

```
for  (int i = 0; i < y.length-1; i++)
{
    sumOfDifferences += (y[i+1] - y[i]); 
    average = (sumOfDifferences) / (weeksData - 1);
    if (y[i+1] <= y[i]) {
        System.out.print("\n You're weekly mileage is NOT increasing!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your weekly mileage is increasing!");
    }
}
```